# Case condition in hql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

What I'm trying to achieve with this query is: always do the "mother" conditional, but if there isn't mother, then do the "dad" conditional, is this posible?

```
"select name from Person where idParents = :idParents and"
                        + " CASE " + 
                        "       WHEN idMother !=NULL THEN idMother = :idMother " + 
                        "       ELSE idFather = :idFather " + 
                        "   END";
```

Comment: But what about HQL? I can't use it? Then how would you achieve that if statement

Comment: I mean... Person has name, idMother and idFather, and i just want the "idFather = :idFather" condition working just when there is no idMother, if there is idMother, i don't want the "father" condition working.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli CASE can be used in WHERE clause in standard SQL.

Comment: Oh you are right. sorry

Comment: @Martinez if idMother is not null but it is not equal to :idMother do you want the join based on idFather? Or idFather will be used **only** if idMother is null?

Comment: I just want one result, the mother condition. but if there is no result, add the father condition, idFather will only be used if the query with the mother condition doesn't find any register, i don't know if that's posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select name 
from Person 
where idParents = :idParents 
and 1 = case
  when idMother = :idMother then 1
  when idFather = :iidFather then 1 
end
```

will try to join first by matching the column `idMother` to `:idMother`.
If this is not possible then a match of `idFather` to `:idFather` will be used, if it exists.

This query:

```
select name 
from Person 
where idParents = :idParents 
and 1 = case
  when idMother = :idMother then 1
  when idMother is null and idFather = :idFather then 1 
end
```

will try to join first by matching the column `idMother` to `:idMother`.
If this is not possible then, only if `idMother` is `null`, a match of `idFather` to `:idFather` will be used, if it exists.

Or maybe you want this:

```
select p.name 
from Person p
where p.idParents = :idParents 
and (
  p.idMother = :idMother
  or (
    p.idFather = :idFather
    and not exists (select 1 from Person where idParents = p.idParents and idMother = :idMother)
  )
)
```

Comment: The second one is the nearest, but i get 2 registers, one from the mother condition, which idMother is not null and idFather is, and one from idFather where idMother is null, is there any way to choose just the mother register?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *2 registers*. In a table like  `Person` each row must be unique either by an id column or by name. So the result should be unique rows under the conditions that you set. That *one from idFather where idMother is null* is returned because this is the requirement in your question: *always do the "mother" conditional, but if there isn't mother, then do the "dad" conditional*

Comment: See my 3d query.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you mate, could you upvote my question please?